# Removing a node from a XML File in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have an XML file that is formatted like this:

```
<state>
  <image>
      <imageUrl>./testImages/testimage.png</imageUrl>
      <perspective id="0">
          <zoomLevel>1.0</zoomLevel>
          <offsetX>0.0</offsetX>
          <offsetY>0.0</offsetY>
      </perspective>
      <perspective id="1">
          <zoomLevel>1.0</zoomLevel>
          <offsetX>0.0</offsetX>
          <offsetY>0.0</offsetY>
      </perspective>
  </image>
</state>
```

In that file, I have multiple image nodes, but that is not the point. What I'd like is to be able to remove the < image > node (and all its child nodes)from the document.

I have the following code so far:

```
private void updateImageElement(Element image, Model model) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException{
    Element rootElement = doc.getDocumentElement();

    rootElement.removeChild(image);
    image.getParentNode().removeChild(image);
}
```

The "rootElement.removeChild(image);" line throws the following exception:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: NOT_FOUND_ERR: An attempt is made to reference a node in a context where it does not exist.
```

Which is weird, because if I print "rootElement", it displays "state", which IS image's parent node.

I then tried the following line ("image.getParentNode().removeChild(image)). This one doesn't throw an Exception, but nothing is removed either.

If I print that line, it also says the parent node is "state, so I can't even figure out what the difference between the two lines is.

Comment: Can you produce a short but *complete* program (ideally a console app) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @Jon Skeet I'll keep that in mind next time, I thought this snippet was enough to show the problem, but Ted Hopp's answer proved otherwise since my error wasn't in it. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are working with two copies of the DOM for that document, and that `doc` is for one copy and `image` is from the other. You don't show the code that is responsible for setting `doc` and `image`, but you need to make sure that they are from the same node tree.

Comment: You are correct. I forgot to change the reference back to the same document after some testing. Thanks a lot